# Count a collection in a sails.js model query

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I wonder if there is a way to count a collection that exists in the model I want to query. I tried this:

```
Event.find({ limit: { '>': attenders.length }}).limit(5).populateAll().exec(function(err, events) {
    });
```

Because I just want to get events where the number of attending persons is less than the limit. This does not work, but is there a similar way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this directly with Waterline, since association information is not stored in the same collection as the model. You'll have to count the `attenders` in a separate query, if possible.

A better way around this would be to maintain an `attender` count in the `Event` model itself and update it when someone joins or leaves an `Event`.